# Segmentation fault when using pthreads

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I'm having a segmentation fault while i'm doing a simulation of a metro station using threads 
The idea i'm going with is that i have 4 stations with 4 paths and 4 trains each train goes by a path to a certain station and the train moves by a thread my initial simulation was working just find until i try to enter a 4th thread ("Train") to my world where i start getting segmentation fault (core dumbed ) 
 I got these as my structs :

```
struct Path {  
 int Direction; //if equals to 1 it's to the tunnel   0 it's away from the tunnel 
   int size;
   char name[25];  // A or B or C or D
   int Used;
};
 struct train {

   int TrainId;
   int   speed;
   int position;
   int direction;
   struct Path CurPath;

};
```

some paths initializers

```
 struct Path PathA; //Path A inital Info 
    PathA.Direction = 1 ;
    strcpy( PathA.name, "A");
    PathA.size = 20;
    paths[0]=PathA;
```

some train initializers as well :

```
   train1->speed = 20;
   train1->CurPath = PathA;
   train1->TrainId = 1;
   train1->direction = 1;
   train1->position = 0;
 pthread_create(&train1Th, NULL, run, (void *)train1);
```

and the run method for the thread :

```
void *run (void  *Train){
    //sleep(1);
    int i;
    struct train *Trains= (struct train*)Train;
    if((*Trains).TrainId == 1)
    i=0;
    if((*Trains).TrainId == 2)
    i=2;
    if((*Trains).TrainId == 3)
    i=0;
    if((*Trains).TrainId == 4)
    i=2;


    while(run){
    sleep(1);
    if((*Trains).TrainId == 1)
    if (i==8) i=0;
    if((*Trains).TrainId == 2)
    if (i==6) i=2;
    if((*Trains).TrainId == 3)
    if (i>8) i=0;
    if((*Trains).TrainId == 4)
    if (i>8) i=0;
    (*Trains).CurPath = paths[i];
    paths[i].Used = 0;
    if((*Trains).CurPath.Used == 1){ puts("Busy waiting");
    sleep(2);}

        printf("\nThe Train is on path : %s,is now at the endpoint with an id of %d", (*Trains).CurPath.name, (*Trains).TrainId);

    paths[i].Used == 1; 
    if((*Trains).TrainId == 1)
    i=i+4;
    if((*Trains).TrainId == 2)
    i=i+2;
    if((*Trains).TrainId == 3)
    i=i+7;
    if((*Trains).TrainId == 4)
    i=i+5;

    }
```

where the i is just for path choosing 
any ideas for what causing the segmentation fault when trying to add a new train ?
Here's a copy of my code as whole :

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include<sys/time.h>

    int semtime =20;
    struct Path {
       int Direction; //if equals to 1 it's to the tunnel   0 it's away from the tunnel 
       int size;
       char name[25];  // A or B or C or D
       int Used;
    };
    struct train {

       int TrainId;
       int   speed;
       int position;
       int direction;
       struct Path CurPath;

    }; 
     struct Path paths[8];
    void *run (void  *Train){
        //sleep(1);
        int i;
        struct train *Trains= (struct train*)Train;
        if((*Trains).TrainId == 1)
        i=0;
        if((*Trains).TrainId == 2)
        i=2;
        if((*Trains).TrainId == 3)
        i=0;
        if((*Trains).TrainId == 4)
        i=2;


        while(run){
        sleep(1);
        if((*Trains).TrainId == 1)
        if (i==8) i=0;
        if((*Trains).TrainId == 2)
        if (i==6) i=2;
        if((*Trains).TrainId == 3)
        if (i>8) i=0;
        if((*Trains).TrainId == 4)
        if (i>8) i=0;
        (*Trains).CurPath = paths[i];
        paths[i].Used = 0;
        if((*Trains).CurPath.Used == 1){ puts("Busy waiting");
        sleep(2);}

            printf("\nThe Train is on path : %s,is now at the endpoint with an id of %d", (*Trains).CurPath.name, (*Trains).TrainId);

        paths[i].Used == 1; 
        if((*Trains).TrainId == 1)
        i=i+4;
        if((*Trains).TrainId == 2)
        i=i+2;
        if((*Trains).TrainId == 3)
        i=i+7;
        if((*Trains).TrainId == 4)
        i=i+5;

        }
        //printf("%02d:%02d:%02d\n", tm->tm_hour, tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec);

     /*   time_t now = time( NULL);

        struct tm now_tm = *localtime( &now);


        struct tm then_tm = now_tm;
        then_tm.tm_sec += semtime;   // add 50 seconds to the time

        mktime( &then_tm);      // normalize it

        printf( "%s\n", asctime( &now_tm));
        printf( "%s\n", asctime( &then_tm));
    */

            return NULL;

     }

    int main( ) {  
        /* Initilizing Paths */
       struct Path PathA; //Path A inital Info 
        PathA.Direction = 1 ;
        strcpy( PathA.name, "A");
        PathA.size = 20;
        paths[0]=PathA;

       struct Path PathA2; //Path A inital Info The other direction
        PathA.Direction = 0 ;
        strcpy( PathA.name, "A");
        PathA.size = 20;
        paths[1]=PathA2;

       struct Path PathB; //Path B inital Info
        malloc(sizeof(struct Path));
        PathB.Direction = 1 ;
        strcpy( PathB.name, "B");
        PathB.size = 20;
        paths[2]=PathB;

       struct Path PathB2; //Path A inital Info The other direction
        PathB2.Direction = 0 ;
        strcpy( PathB2.name, "B");
        PathB2.size = 20;
        paths[3]=PathB2;

       struct Path PathC; //Path c inital Info
        PathC.Direction = 1 ;
        strcpy( PathC.name, "C");
        PathC.size = 20;
        paths[4]=PathC;

       struct Path PathC2; //Path C inital Info The other direction
        PathC2.Direction = 0 ;
        strcpy( PathC2.name, "C");
        PathC2.size = 20;
        paths[5]=PathC2;

       struct Path PathD; //Path D inital Info
        PathD.Direction = 1 ;
        strcpy( PathD.name, "D");
        PathD.size = 20;
        paths[6]=PathD;

       struct Path PathD2; //Path D inital Info The other direction
        PathD2.Direction = 0 ;
        strcpy( PathD2.name, "D");
        PathD2.size = 20;
        paths[7]=PathD;

       struct train *train1;  
       pthread_t train1Th;

       train1->speed = 20;
       train1->CurPath = PathA;
       train1->TrainId = 1;
       train1->direction = 1;
       train1->position = 0;
     pthread_create(&train1Th, NULL, run, (void *)train1);


       struct train *train2;  
       pthread_t train2Th;

       train2->speed = 20;
       train2->CurPath = PathB;
       train2->TrainId = 2;
       train2->direction = 1;
       train2->position = 0;

     pthread_create(&train2Th, NULL, run, (void *)train2);

     struct train *train3;  
     pthread_t train3Th;


   train3->speed = 20;
   train3->CurPath = PathA;
   train3->TrainId = 3;
   train3->direction = 1;
   train3->position = 0;

 pthread_create(&train3Th, NULL, run, (void *)train3);


     struct train *train4;
        train4->TrainId = 4;


       return 0;
    }
```

the error is happening when i try to access TrainId

Comment: Can you post the full code, properly indented and with `Train->` instead of `(*Train).`?

Comment: I posted the full code, but what is Train-> instead of (*Train). for?

Comment: and the code works just fine with three threads "Trains" but i get the error when trying to add the fourth one

Comment: `Train->` and `(*Train.)` mean the same but the former is more readable.

Comment: Is that the full code?   train1, train2, train4 don’t seem to be pointing at anything; which could explain your fault.   It might be nice to compile your code with reasonable warnings resolved before turning for help...

Comment: `train4->TrainId = 4;` will be a seg fault, since there is nothing allocated to `*train4` on the line below

Comment: do you mean the rest of the struct members or memory allocation for the pointer ?

Comment: regarding: `while(run)`  Exactly what are you trying to do?  the 'run' is the address of the thread function!  If you want a 'forever' loop suggest using `while(1)`  or `for(;;)`

Comment: the 4th train is never completely setup

Comment: the calls to `pthread_create()` are passing the first 4 bytes of a 'struct train' to the thread function: `run()`  what you should be doing is passing the address of a `struct train`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace (including those optional one) '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace /}/.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: it is a very poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not used.  Suggest removing the unused header file include statements

Comment: Suggest learning about the `switch()` statement, then using that statement rather than  implementing a separate `if()` code block for each train.  (what if there were 100 trains?)

Comment: in the function: `run()`, the use of the `i` variable is very vague.  Variable names (and parameter names) should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both)  Variable names like `i` are meaningless, even in the current context

Comment: in the thread function: `run()`, these two statements: `paths[i].Used = 0;` and `paths[i].Used =- 1;`  The code between these two statements does not use 'path' so why is it even mentioned?

Comment: the preferred method of exiting a thread function is: `pthread_exit()` not `return NULL;`

Comment: near the end of the `main()` function should be a loop that calls `pthread_join()` for each thread that is created.

Comment: each of the statements, like: `struct train *train3` are not setting that pointer to point to an instance of a `struct train`  so any and all statements like: `train3->` are candidates for a seg fault event.  Because that pointer will contain what ever trash happened to be on the stack where that pointer exists

Comment: suggest using an array of `strut train`  and an array of `struct Path`, Then adding/deleting a train would be trivial rather than a major problem

Comment: this is the declaration of the array: `paths[]`  "struct Path paths[8];` so this kind of statement: `paths[1]=PathA2;` will not work.  Suggest something similar to: `memcpy( &paths[1], &PathA2 );`  Of course, there is no need to declare statements like: `struct Path PathA;` when all the fields are available in `paths[0].<field>`

Comment: the data being set into each instance of `struct train` is fixed.  Suggest using a table that contains the data for each train and using that table to initialize each instance of a train.

Comment: Thank you for such a great advices !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, you try to affect a value to unallocated memory:

```
    struct train *train1;
    // you declare a pointer to a structure train, but your struct does not exists in memory

    train1->speed = 20;
    // and then, you initialize an unallocated memory with a value
```

The simpliest is probably to use train structure instead of pointer to structure (you will avoid problems of allocating and freeing memory) and gives the address of the structure when starting your thread:

```
    struct train train1;

    train1.speed = 20;
    [...]
    pthread_create(&train1Th, NULL, run, (void *)&train1);
```